# libvirt - virbr0 - setting the IP address

Tags: networking, libvirt

I am having issues with setting the IP address of the virbr0 interface created by libvirtd.  I have configured a different IP in the xml file that configures networking (or so I thought), but it still defaults to 192.168.124.1.  I did a grep through /etc and didn't find any matches.

Where is this coming from?  I'd like to have it specified to whatever I want so my firewall can allow for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way fo changing address is using [virsh](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html/).
You can stop network (e.g. ifdown):

```
virsh net-destroy default
```

And you can start it with:

```
virsh net-start default
```

As you edited default.xml file this should be enough. But for editing you can use:

```
virsh net-edit default
```

Comment: Even though I edited the right file, it appears there must be a cached file somewhere else with the original value.  I'll use those commands to make the edits.  I think I probably just need to destroy the network configuration, overlay my file, then start it.

Comment: Also you can point a file to create network: virsh net-create /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml. But you can check options with virsh help.

Comment: @taliezin using virsh net-destroy default, editing the file directly with vi with the file path you specified (although, I think virsh net-edit default does the same thing), then virsh net-create as you gave it worked for me. Thanks.